# c++ Why i need pointer casting each time i request method from container object

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

i have annoying problem where i need to pointer cast  pointer member 
here is example

```
class GlobalInterface
{
   public:  
   virtual void DoAction() = 0;
}

class ActionClass_A: public GlobalInterface
{
   public:
       ActionClass_A(){};
       ~ActionClass_A(){};
       void DoAction() { ..... } ;
       void DoSomeActionOnlyForA() { ..... } ;

}

class ActionClass_B: public GlobalInterface
{
   public:
       ActionClass_B(){};
       ~ActionClass_B(){};
       void DoAction() { ..... } ;
        void DoSomeActionOnlyForB() { ..... } ;

}

#include "GlobalInterface.h"
#include "ActionClass_A.h"
#include "ActionClass_B.h"

class GlobalContainer()
{
    public:
    GlobalContainer(GlobalInterface* _action)
    {
          pAction = _action;
    }
    GlobalInterface* getAction() { return pAction; };
    private:
    GlobalInterface* pAction;

}

// Main
GlobalContainer* pGlobalContainer = new GlobalContainer(new ActionClass_B());

// WHY i need this casting to get the ActionClass_B DoAction()???
((ActionClass_B*)pGlobalContainer->getAction())->DoSomeActionOnlyForA();
```

i just want to avoid this casting , and call it like this :
and it will know which implamention it should invoke based on the object type

```
  pGlobalContainer->getAction()->DoSomeActionOnlyForA()
    or
     pGlobalContainer->getAction()->DoSomeActionOnlyForB()
```

Comment: `'virtual void GlobalInterface::DoAction()' is private`

Comment: Also, doesn't the error message tell you the exact answer to your question?

Comment: fixed the private thingi

Answer (score 2):

The virtual function in the base class is private. It should work with a public function.

Answer (score 0):

> ...  and it will know which implamention it should invoke based on the
>   object type.

But you're not letting it decide what implementation it should invoke based on type, you're trying to make that decision yourself by calling `DoSomeActionOnlyForA()` or `DoSomeActionOnlyForB()` directly.

This doesn't work because at the moment of the call the static type of the object is `GlobalInterface*` and the `GlobalInterface` class doesn't have member functions named like that.

The way to achieve what you want, let each derived class have it's own behavior, is to understand and use virtual functions correctly. For example you could do this:

```
class GlobalInterface
{
public:
    virtual ~GlobalInterface() {}
    virtual void DoAction() = 0;
};

class ActionClass_A: public GlobalInterface
{
public:
    ActionClass_A() {}
    ~ActionClass_A() {}

    void DoAction()
    {
        DoSomeActionOnlyForA(); // call specific action for A
    }

    void DoSomeActionOnlyForA() { /* implement specific action for A */ } ;
};

class ActionClass_B: public GlobalInterface
{
public:
    ActionClass_B() {}
    ~ActionClass_B() {}

    void DoAction()
    {
        DoSomeActionOnlyForB(); // call specific action for B
    }

    void DoSomeActionOnlyForB() { /* implement specific action for B */ } ;
};
```

As you can see, you have a virtual function `DoAction()` that is overridden in each of the derived classes to call the appropriate functionality for that class.

Then you can use it like this:

```
GlobalContainer* pGlobalContainer = new GlobalContainer(new ActionClass_B());

pGlobalContainer->getAction()->DoAction();
```

This will call `ActionClass_B::DoAction()` which in turn calls `ActionClass_B::DoSomeActionOnlyForB()`.

If you instead create the container like this:

```
GlobalContainer* pGlobalContainer = new GlobalContainer(new ActionClass_A());
```

then the same call `pGlobalContainer->getAction()->DoAction();` will instead call `ActionClass_A::DoAction()` which in turn calls the appropriate functionality for A.

As you can see, in this case it does indeed call the appropriate function based on the dynamic type of the object (`DoAction()` from A or from B).

Comment: thanks for your replay, i wanted to avoid this ... 
i was thinking that it will be Smart enough to know which Implemented Class i init the  GlobalInterface* pAction; pointer

Comment: It does *know* in a way, that's why it calls the correct `DoAction()` method at runtime. But you have to play by the rules and let it know your intentions, in this case by using virtual methods, otherwise the dynamic dispatch won't work. You can't call random methods on random objects and expect it to figure things out on it's own. Think for example that the pointer is initialized someplace else(e.g. a different file/library); the compiler has no way of knowing the exact type of the object (the dynamic type), this can only happen at runtime. Read on Virtual Function Table to see how it works.